# How to use my function in Node.js/AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda

I'm creating an AWS Lambda function based on Node.js. Within this function (function A), among different things, I need to call another lambda function (Function B).

I did the test of creating a test lambda function (function C) that just handle the call to function B :

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var lambda = new aws.Lambda;
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
lambda.invoke({
  FunctionName: 'dynamoCatego',
  Payload: '{ "catid": "40000000"}'
}, function(err, data){
  if(err){console.log(err, err.stack);} // an error occurred
  else {callback(null, JSON.parse(data.Payload));} // successful response
}
)};
```

It work perfectly, I got the result I want from the function.

Now, I want to integrate inline this piece of code into the function A, and typically have a variable (typeA) that would be equal of the results of the call( for a provided payload). And I'm stuck here...

I tried, roughly, to copy/paste the piece of code into the main function. The result is not retrieved, then the created variable has no value at all.

I guess what I would need to do is to define the sub-function in the root of the lambda function and, when I need it, invoke it with a specific payload.

If anyone can guide me in the right direction, I'll be really thankful

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of wrapping a remote) lambda function in another lambda handler:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const lambda = new aws.Lambda();

// this is a specific lambda function wrapper,
// you could make it more general if needed.
// (i.e. make FunctionName the first argument.
async function dynamoCatego(args) {
  const FunctionName = 'dynamoCatego';
  const Payload = JSON.parse(args);
  // use .promise() to return a promise that can be awaited,
  // rather than deal with nested callbacks:
  const data = await lambda.invoke({ FunctionName, Payload }).promise();
  // n.b. this will just throw if there's an error,
  // so you may choose to try, catch it.
  return JSON.parse(data.Payload || 'null');
  // (Payload will be undefined if nothing is returned, but JSON.parse(undefined) is an error
}

exports.handler = async function handler(event, context, callback) {
  // other things...
  const result = await dynamoCatego({ catid: '40000000' });
  // other things...
  callback(null, result);
}
```

Note the use of async/await means you will need to use Node 8.10 (AWS does give you the option of 6.10 too, but there's little reason to use the older version except for legacy projects). You can, instead, do this with nested callbacks, but I'd argue this approach is much more readable.

If you *really* want to use callbacks, though, you can do it like this:

```
const Aws = require('aws-sdk');
const lambda = new Aws.Lambda();

function dynamoCatego(args, cb) {
  const FunctionName = 'dynamoCatego';
  const Payload = JSON.parse(args);
  lambda.invoke({ FunctionName, Payload }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) { throw err; }
    const result = JSON.parse(data.Payload);
    cb(result);
  });
}

exports.handler = function handler(event, context, callback) {
  // other things...
  dynamoCatego({ catid: '40000000' }, (result) => {
    // do things with the result...
    callback(null, result);
  });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I understand better now. Now, I got the issue with sync/async function, as my handler is sync. So I cannot use await in it. Any ideas how I can overcome this ? Can you explain a bit more the nested callbacks option ? thanks!

Comment: There's nothing to stop you from making your handler async (just add the word async before it), which will make everything much more terse. You could also use the promises directly with .then() (e.g. have dynamoCatego return the promise.) If you really want to stick with callbacks, you'll need to add a callback to the dynamoCatego function that it passes to the invoke function (rather than using . promise()).

Comment: Unfortunately, still stuck..I'm finally declaring my function B directly in the function A. The problem is still that the callback takes longer, so the function continue and I'm not able to return the value before the next operations..

Comment: I've updated my example to include an approach using callbacks. Fundamentally invoking a remote function is asynchronous- it's literally happening on another computer. That means you need to be comfortable with using callbacks (i.e. a function that is called once the invoke has completed), promises (a special type that resolves/rejects once the invoke has completed) or async/await (a shorthand syntax for awaiting the invoke to complete). Over time node has evolved from using callbacks to async/await because you end up nesting callbacks within callbacks and it all gets very hard to read.